# Discount Subway/Other Ticket options for New York City for Students?

Tags: budget, public-transport, tickets, new-york-city

Which public transportation ticket would you recommend (cheap and with unlimited rides within the City of New York, especially Manhattan) for two guys who want to visit NYC only (no suburbs) this summer. The stay in NYC is about 5 days (Wednesday till Sunday). We both are students from Germany and are equipped with both international student ID and student ID of our home university in Munich. Are there some discounts for students like us?

Comment: What does 'best' mean? cheapest? most convenient? most inclusive?

Comment: Since we both are students we want to get a cheap option, but also being independent from time and place (unlimited rides during our whole stay)

Comment: ok, so edit your post. Also, you should tell where you want to go : only NYC or suburban trains too?

Comment: Please note that since May 27, 2013, New York City has a bike rental network, named [Citi Bike](http://citibikenyc.com/).

Comment: edited to remove subjective "best" (see [faq] saying not to use that), and reworded to help. Added answer too.

Comment: @mouviciel Biking in NYC is not for the faint of heart. :)

Comment: MTA did away with student discounts in 2011.  The only student discounts left you won't qualify for. :)

Comment: @Karlson- Not yet!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was there last month, and while there's no additional student discount, every traveller (pretty much) in the hostel used a 7 day Metro Card, for $30 (plus a $1 activation fee for the card).

This and other options (hop-on/hop-off bus) for you to look at are available on the [relevant NYC Transportation page](http://www.newyorkpass.com/En/new-york-subway-transportation/).

It was honestly the most convenient option. The subway goes almost anywhere you could possibly want to go as a tourist in that time (I also stayed five days), and considering the price of a single journey, it's well worth getting.

Comment: The 7 day is now $30, and there is also a one time fee of 1$ to activate a new card, so you're looking at $31 for 7 days of unlimited travel. Still a bargain. Remember, the Subway runs 24/7, goes nearly everywhere, and for the handful of outliers, works for the majority of buses as well.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz hah, I thought it didn't sound familiar (the price) - thanks for the clarification, will update.